# How to prevent SIM (not eSIM) from getting signal?

Tags: iphone, sim, esim, signal-strength

I want my SIM to utilize Wifi calling using the internet eSIM provides.

I tried changing "network selection" from auto to specific options. It works only sometimes to get no signal

Comment: @ChanganAuto You're wrong, Wi-Fi calling on one sim can use the data plan of a second sim card. On this Support doc, go to "Learn about Dual SIM status icons " and review the third screenshot https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209044